# Can my Specialist degree be equalized to Bachelor degree?

Tags: degree, bachelor, canada, russia

I have graduated from Russian university after 5 years of education and got a Specialist degree (Engineer in Computer Science). [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_degree), Specialist is a four-tier degree and stands right above Master degree in some specialities. But despite graduation requirements and due to the duration, I suggest, it can only be put right above Bachelor degree. So the next step I should take is to continue my education to then get Master degree. Is my suggestion right? Or do I think about it wrong way?

If it helps or is necessary, I'm planning to continue education in Canadian university.

Comment: What level do you want to enrol at the Canadian university? They are the ones who have to decide if your title is enough requirement or you need to upgrade it.

Comment: I want to earn a M.Sc. degree. After all, I understand that the only way to get most reliable answer is to ask a university representative. But I believe I could get useful advice or even direct answer from community, too.

Comment: Sorry, but indeed the university folks are the only ones who can answer this question.

Comment: There are services, such as WES (www.wes.org), that will evaluate your foreign credentials into US equivalent. I am not sure, if Canadian institutions accept it.

Comment: You would need something in the lines of : http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/assessment.asp to be sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [1997](http://int.rsue.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=175&Itemid=209#Degrees), having a Russian (or rather "Soviet"-style) 5-year [Specialist (специалист) degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_degree) is formally recognized as the equivalent of holding a Master's degree (cf. [*Mutual Recognition of Qualifications: the Russian Federation and the Other European Countries*](http://unesdoc.unesco.org/images/0012/001298/129839eo.pdf)); Judging by the fact that, [in Canada, one can typically directly enter a PhD program without e.g. doing a Master's degree course beforehand](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/14662) (as is typical in e.g. the USA), you should have no problems fulfilling the formal requirements to enter a PhD program there.

Answer (score 4):

I am in a German masters program, and one of my Russian classmates has a specialist degree (in applied mathematics). I cannot say in generality (i.e. Canada), but it was taken as equivalent to a Bachelor's Degree around here.